# Get value from root element xml to column

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Problem with adding root element .
Use mssql server 2017.
XML example:

```sql
DECLARE @XML XML = '
<FileId global_id="1234">
  <file id="12aa"><vd>3</vd>
    <pl_a type_a ="111" k="111" name="aaa"></pl_a>
    <period from="2019-04-01" to="2019-06-30"></period>
    <all>1</all>
  </file>
  <file id="12bb"><vd>3</vd>
    <pl_b type_b ="222" k="222" name="bbb"></pl_b>
    <period from="2019-04-01" to="2019-06-30"></period>
    <all>2</all>
  </file>
</FileId>'
```

I've tryed this query:

```sql
SELECT F.[File].value(N'@global_id','varchar(100)') as id_payment,
       F.[File].value('@id', 'varchar(4)') AS id,
       ISNULL(F.[File].value('(pl_a/@type_a)[1]', 'int'), F.[File].value('(pl_b/@type_a)[1]', 'int')) AS type_a,
       ISNULL(F.[File].value('(pl_a/@type_b)[1]', 'int'), F.[File].value('(pl_b/@type_b)[1]', 'int')) AS type_b,
       ISNULL(F.[File].value('(pl_a/@k)[1]', 'int'), F.[File].value('(pl_b/@k)[1]', 'int')) AS k,
       ISNULL(F.[File].value('(pl_a/@name)[1]', 'varchar(4)'), F.[File].value('(pl_b/@name)[1]', 'varchar(4)')) AS [name],
       F.[File].value('(period/@from)[1]', 'date') AS [date_from],
       F.[File].value('(period/@to)[1]', 'date') AS [date_from],
       F.[File].value('(all/text())[1]', 'int') AS [all]
FROM (VALUES (@XML)) V (X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/FileId/file') F([File]);
```

But query does not get root value.

Expected:

```
global_id id   type_a      type_b      k           name date_from  date_from  all
--------- ---- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---- ---------- ---------- -----------
1234      12aa 111         NULL        111         aaa  2019-04-01 2019-06-30 1
1234      12bb NULL        222         222         bbb  2019-04-01 2019-06-30 2
```

Actual:

```
global_id id   type_a      type_b      k           name date_from  date_from  all
--------- ---- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---- ---------- ---------- -----------
NULL      12aa 111         NULL        111         aaa  2019-04-01 2019-06-30 1
NULL      12bb NULL        222         222         bbb  2019-04-01 2019-06-30 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`../` to get the parent node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256122(v=vs.100)) of the current context node. So you can use `../@global_id` instead of `@global_id` to get the attribute value of the  parent element (`Fileid`):

```sql
-- XML document
DECLARE @XML XML = '
<FileId global_id="1234">
  <file id="12aa"><vd>3</vd>
    <pl_a type_a ="111" k="111" name="aaa"></pl_a>
    <period from="2019-04-01" to="2019-06-30"></period>
    <all>1</all>
  </file>
  <file id="12bb"><vd>3</vd>
    <pl_b type_b ="222" k="222" name="bbb"></pl_b>
    <period from="2019-04-01" to="2019-06-30"></period>
    <all>2</all>
  </file>
</FileId>';

-- SELECT to get some information of the XML document
SELECT F.[File].value(N'../@global_id','varchar(100)') as id_payment,
  F.[File].value('@id', 'varchar(4)') AS id,
  ISNULL(F.[File].value('(pl_a/@type_a)[1]', 'int'),
  F.[File].value('(pl_b/@type_a)[1]', 'int')) AS type_a,
  ISNULL(F.[File].value('(pl_a/@type_b)[1]', 'int'), 
  F.[File].value('(pl_b/@type_b)[1]', 'int')) AS type_b,
  ISNULL(F.[File].value('(pl_a/@k)[1]', 'int'), 
  F.[File].value('(pl_b/@k)[1]', 'int')) AS k,
  ISNULL(F.[File].value('(pl_a/@name)[1]', 'varchar(4)'),
  F.[File].value('(pl_b/@name)[1]', 'varchar(4)')) AS [name],
  F.[File].value('(period/@from)[1]', 'date') AS [date_from],
  F.[File].value('(period/@to)[1]', 'date') AS [date_from],
  F.[File].value('(all/text())[1]', 'int') AS [all]
FROM (VALUES (@XML)) V (X)
  CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/FileId/file') F([File]);
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7ea4b38639a95c6949915794d7f3c0c5)

Comment: Backward navigation (`../`) is very slow... In this case Salman's answer which fetches the value from the XML using `.value()` directly, was much better...

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```sql
SELECT F.[File].value(N'@global_id','varchar(100)') as id_payment
```

To this:

```sql
SELECT V.X.value(N'(/FileId/@global_id)[1]','varchar(100)') as id_payment
```